# jQuery infinite scroll in a DIV scroll event fires more than once

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

i want to implement the infinite scroll technique just in a div not the whole body, i have googled it and i found an answer this is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10072254/3408424) but this solution fires more than once, which causes more than one load !! this is my mark up !!

```
<div id="articlesContainer" class="container-fluid">
   <div id="sideBarArticles" class=" col-md-3">
       //..sidebar goes here
   </div>
   <div id="articleInfinte" class="col-md-9">
       <div class="article">
         //..title.. content goes here
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Js

```
   $("#articleInfinte").scroll(function(){
        if($('#articleInfinte').scrollTop() + $('#articleInfinte').outerHeight() >=        $('#articleInfinte')[0].scrollHeight){
             //Loading data...
             $('#articleInfinte').append(data);
         }
```

Comment: Not a real answer, but check this chrome extension out, helped me a lot with such problems: [Visual Event](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visual-event/pbmmieigblcbldgdokdjpioljjninaim)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a `debounce` like approach. Basically, after data is appended set a variable for a second or two and check for that in your if. If it exists don't append the data.

Comment: i think the calculation is wrong, so is there any formula more accurate !! i have applied your approach but it feels not that CLEAN !!

Comment: It might be better off as a throttle, but it also depends on how you're calling the data. Here's a small demo I set up: http://jsbin.com/xebiwida/1/edit?html,js,output