# Increase the number of a limited number in a variable on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I was able to list the movies from JSON file but I want to increase total number of the limited variable so when I scroll down I add 10 more movies

Here's my code

```
(function () {
    $.getJSON("m.json", function (movie) {
        var limitMovies = [];
        var totalMovies = 10;

        for (var i = 0; i < totalMovies; i++) {
            limitMovies.push(movie[i]);
        }

        var movies = document.getElementById('movies');

        for ( i = 0; i < limitMovies.length; i++ ) {
            var addMovies = '<a id="' + i + '" class="Movie" target="_blank" href="'+ limitMovies[i].url + '/"><img src="' 
                            + limitMovies[i].Poster + '"/></a>';
            movies.innerHTML += addMovies;
        }
        i = 20;
        $(window).scroll(function(){
    });
});
}());
```

Comment: If you use jquery, use jquery everywhere. Please have a better understanding of Async code and the client server architecture simply increasing totalMovies wont do what you want...

Comment: I think you either have to load all your movies and visually hide them, then display them on scroll. OR you have to make a new ajax call everytime you reach the bottom of the document and append them to your container.

Comment: thanks Vincent, this is exactly what i'm trying to do, loading 10 more at the end but i just can't seem to find a better way to do so

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery infinite scroll - with div not scrollbar of body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072216/jquery-infinite-scroll-with-div-not-scrollbar-of-body)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have refactored few bits of your code, and the change I have done is load all movies from file, but append them to container on scroll event. You can take a look at a working version [here](https://jsfiddle.net/87e7hL6z/1/).

```
;
(function () {
    let loadedMovies = [];
  let lastMoviePosition = 0;
  let container = $('#movies');

  $.getJSON("m.json", function (movies) {
        if(movies && movies.length > 0){
           loadedMovies = movies;
           addMovies(10);
        }
  });

    let addMovies = (n) => {
        for(let i=0; i<n && lastMoviePosition < loadedMovies.length; i++){
        var movie = '<a id="' + i + '" class="Movie" target="_blank" href="'+ limitMovies[lastMoviePosition].url + '/"><img src="' 
                        + limitMovies[lastMoviePosition].Poster + '"/></a>';

        container.append(movie);
        lastMoviePosition++;
    }
  };

$(window).scroll(function(){
    addMovies(10);
});

})();
```

Comment: Thanks Dipen , It will be great if it will load some divs before scrolling rather than a black page [link](https://jsfiddle.net/8tqfhzgg/)

Comment: @Argus I'm sure you can add addMovies call on document.ready, to load n movies on page load.

Comment: @Argus https://jsfiddle.net/8tqfhzgg/1/, Mark it as an answer if this is what you've asked

Comment: Wow you're genius *High five*

Answer (score 0):

Add `var limitMovies;` into the first line of your code to make it globally accessible. Remove all `var` in front of other limitMovies declarations. Then do:

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){ 
    limitMovies+=10;
});
```

However, that wont answer your real question. Just increasing the counter wont work. You need to rerun the for loop to parse from that array. Also the `scroll` will fire a thousand times a second, you need another way of detecting it. May have a look at:
https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/
You need to restructure your whole code, this wont fit into an answer on SO...

Comment: Thanks jonas for your reply, i did what you said and unfortunately it doesn't seem to work  .. i thought i could make it without infinite scrolling plugins since they require a next page link while i only have 1 json file

Comment: @argus: you can. And my code works, please read the text after it again...

Comment: Or have a look at https://www.google.de/search?q=js+detect+if+scrolled+to+end&oq=js+detect+if+scrolled+to+end&aqs=chrome..69i57.5954j0j4&client=ms-android-google&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/8tqfhzgg/) here's a link so you can se what im trying to do but i got stuck with scrolling part